# Solving a system of non-linear differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the system of non-linear differential equations given below numerically.

$$y''(t)+500y'(t)+100y(t)=-33\cos(500t)-66\cos(1000t)$$
$$300x'(t)=1000y(t)+500y'(t)-35\tanh(50x'(t))$$

Notice that there is a derivative of $x$ inside $\tanh$. I tried the code below, but many errors appeared.

```
sol1 = 
  NDSolve[{y''[t] + 500 y'[t] + 100 y[t] == -33 Cos[500 t] - 66 Cos[1000 t],
    y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 30}];
sol2 = 
  NDSolve[{300 x'[t] == 
    1000 First[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol1]] + 500 First[Evaluate[y'[t] /. sol1]] - 
    35 Tanh[50 x'[t]], x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 30}];
Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sol1], Evaluate[y[t] /. sol2]}, {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

How can I solve my system of differential equations using *Mathematica*?

#### Edit

I found the answer! thanks to Nasser. The solution for $x(t)$ is like below. I just need to adjust the axis

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the solution supposed to be something like this? Hopefully I did not break too many things. You should know if the solution looks right or not.

```
Clear[y, x, t];
eqs = y''[t] + 500 y'[t] + 100 y[t] == -33 Cos[500 t] - 66 Cos[1000 t];
ic = {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};
sol1 = First@NDSolve[{eqs, ic},{y[t], y'[t]}, {t, 0, 30},Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
eqs = 300 x'[t] == 1000 Evaluate[y[t] /. sol1] + 500 Evaluate[y'[t] /. sol1] - 
   35 Tanh[50 x'[t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{eqs, x[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 30},MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[{{Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol1], {t, 0, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All]},
  {Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol2], {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you! i edited my question to include the answer.

Comment: But if it is okay, I would like to know the reason for using StiffnessSwitching and MaxSteps->Infinity...

Comment: "StiffnessSwitching", well, more information on this is here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessSwitching.html. Physics wise, the natural frequency of your eqs is 10 rad/sec, while the forcing frequencies (RHS) are much higher (you have one at 1000 rad/sec). So it tells one that system will oscillate slowly in the early transient stage, then in steady state, when the load takes over, system will oscillate at much higher frequency (at the driving frequency). Hence you have a system with low and high vibrations in it. Hence this method to try....

Comment: ..."MaxSteps->Infinity" this one is easy. Mathematica gave an error saying `Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 1.5727575203`, so you just increase the number of steps and hope for the best.